# why does sql use single quotes for string literals but other programming languages use double quotes?

Tags: sql

im currently studying IT and my lecturer just explained that in the ANSI standard for SQL, single quotes are used for strings. just wondering where this standard came from and why it is different from other languages.

Comment: Who says it is different than other programming languages?  In Python, for example, string literals can be single or double quotes, same is true for R.

Comment: And JavaScript.

Comment: I'd consider checking out some mainframe keyboards from back in the 70s. There might be some clues there.

Comment: Pascal and COBOL also use single quotes for strings - both were very popular when SQL was created.

Answer (score 2):

It is because double quotes is reserved for names literals like `"My strange name database"."my other name schema"."my even other name table"."also column name"`. Authors included that is more natural to use `"` for name literals and SQL is designed to be as natural language as possible.
In other hand many programming languages use `'` for string literals.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the possibility that this was also inspired by COBOL which was very popular when SQL was first created.

Answer (score 1):

That may be because typing `'` is easier than typing SHIFT+`'`.